# On SQL insert, write the new row's assigned ID in a second column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have the following table

```
| id | name   | anchorId |
|----|--------|----------|
| 1  | Robert | 1        |
| 2  | William| 2        |
| 3  | Bob    | 1        |
```

Basically, let's say a new row gets added

```
| id | name   | anchorId |
|----|--------|----------|
| 1  | Robert | 1        |
| 2  | William| 2        |
| 3  | Bob    | 1        |
| 4  | Billy  | 4        |
```

Until I can get to and point set Billy's anchorId to 2, it, I would like it to refer to itself.
Namely, on insert, if unspecified, how can set anchorId to be the newly assigned id?

Comment: What is your end goal here? If it's for your presentation layer, why not use `ISNULL(anchorId,id) AS AnchorId`? If it's for your `ON`/`WHERE` clause, then why not `WHERE (AnchorID = @Variable OR (AnchorID IS NULL and id = @Variable))`? You can't default a column to the value of another column, so the only way you could likely achieve this would be with a trigger; which may not be ideal.

Comment: I would suggest leaving it NULL. This looks like an adjacency list and if you link it to itself you can end up with endless recursion if you are not careful.

Answer (score 1):

Some choices (most preferential first IMO)

1. Set the `anchorId` to `NULL` for new inserts instead of to the row ID. This is the usual way of representing this.
2. Use a sequence instead of an `IDENTITY` - then you can set the default for both `id` and `anchorId` to be from the sequence and both will be assigned the same value.
3. If using an `IDENTITY` you will need to do the `INSERT` then followed by an immediate `UPDATE` on the newly inserted value (using the `IDENTITY` value returned from `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` or the `OUTPUT` clause or the `INSERTED` table in a trigger).

**Code for 2**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE S1 AS INT START WITH 1;

CREATE TABLE T1
(
id INT NOT NULL DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR S1,
name varchar(50),
anchorid INT  NOT NULL DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR S1
)

INSERT INTO T1 (name) VALUES ('foo');

SELECT *
FROM T1
```